# Exception with Convexity Defects

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, convexity-defects

I am trying get Convexity Defects from the following code, but keep getting a unhandled exception. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
vector<Vec4i> defects;
ContourPoly = vector<Point>(contour.size());
approxPolyDP( Mat(contour), ContourPoly,20, false );
convexHull(Mat(ContourPoly), HullPoints, false, true);
// The following line wont work
convexityDefects(Mat(ContourPoly),HullPoints,defects);
```

While HullPoints are of type `vector<Point>`
The exception is as follows

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion Failed (ptnum >3) is unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1969
```

But with  `vector<Point> defects;` or `vector<Vec4i> defects`
I get the following exception

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion Failed (hull.checkVector(1,CV_32S) is unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1971
```

Comment: Which of these causes triggers the exception? What does your debug say?

Comment: I just added an the exception

Comment: `ptnum >3` assertion means that your `HullPoints` contains less than 3 points which is minimum required for `convexityDefects`

Comment: No luck I tried it again, now its giving me the second error I mentioned above\

Answer (score 0):

`defects` should be `vector<Vec4i>`

From the documentation:

> each convexity defect is represented as 4-element integer vector (a.k.a. `cv::Vec4i`): `(start_index, end_index, farthest_pt_index, fixpt_depth)`, where indices are 0-based indices in the original contour of the convexity defect beginning, end and the farthest point, and `fixpt_depth` is fixed-point approximation (with 8 fractional bits) of the distance between the farthest contour point and the hull. That is, to get the floating-point value of the depth will be `fixpt_depth/256.0`

Comment: But I have set the last argument to true for convexHull method, returning vector<Point>, shouldn't defects be of vector<Point> as well? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: It is specific for `convexityDefects` only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
vector<vector<Vec4i> > defects;
```

should be:

```
vector<vector<Vec4i> > defects( contour.size() );
```

Also, before calling `convexityDefects` function, check if the size of the `HullPoints` is greater than 3.